# Rsync to copy specific subfolders and files to new directory

Tags: rsync, file-copy

**Original path, RootFolderI:**

```
RootFolderI/FolderA/Subfolder1/Subsub1/JPG1.jpg -> want this jpg
RootFolderI/FolderA/Subfolder2/Subsub1/JPG2.jpg -> want this jpg
RootFolderI/FolderA/Subfolder2/Subsub2/JPG3.jpg
. . .
RootFolderI/FolderB/Subfolder1/Subsub1/JPG4.jpg -> want this jpg
RootFolderI/FolderB/Subfolder2/Subsub1/JPG5.jpg -> want this jpg
RootFolderI/FolderB/Subfolder3/Subsub2/JPG6.jpg
...
```

There are many folders FolderA/B/C/etc, but the structure of folders inside is always the same (except the files, they are different)

---

I want to copy to `RootFolderII`:

- only all the FolderA/B/etc
- all the files in Subsub1

**...Resulting is this new path, RootFolderII:**

```
RootFolderII/FolderA/ with JPG1.jpg, JPG2.jpg
RootFolderII/FolderB/ with JPG4.jpg,JPG5.jpg
```

---

**I've got at the moment the following code (but it's not working):**

```
rsync -r --include='Folder*/Subfolder1/Subsub1/***' --exclude="/*/*/" /RootFolderI/ /RootFolderII/
```

Where

`--exclude="/*/*/"`  : creates FolderA/B/... -> working

`--include='Folder*/Subfolder1/Subsub1/***'`  : i want to copy all files (not the structure) ... -> it's not working

`???` well, I think that even if it was working, it would copy files from FolderB to FolderA, and I don't want that!

Comment: How do we identify which files you do want, and which you don't? (i.e. why don't you want JPG3.jpg?)

Comment: I don't want files from all "Subsub2" folders. Inside FolderA/B/C/etc the structure/naming of folders is the same. Only the files are different

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

```
rsync -r --include='*.jpg' --exclude="*" /RootFolderI/Folder*/Subfolder1/Subsub1/. /RootFolderII/.
```

Comment: thanks. The problem is that I need to create that middle "Folder*" too (FolderA/B/etc) , and I need those jpg files in the right "Folder*".

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd accomplish that. with a single rsync command. I would use a for loop. Something like `for DIR in /RootFolderI/Folder*;do rsync -r --include='*.jpg' --exclude="*" ${DIR}/Subfolder1/Subsub1/. $(basename ${DIR})/.;done`

Answer (score 1):

What I did:

- `rsync` with includes and excludes
- Move files up (2level up)

  ```
  find /folder/ -type f -mindepth 3 -execdir mv -t ../../ -- {} +
  ```
- Delete empty folders

  ```
  find /folder/*/ -type d -empty -delete
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I would use `rsync` for this task. (There's no delta algorithm, so little to be gained by using it.) Here's a version using `cp`:

```
for rfipath in RootFolderI/*
do
    folder="${rfipath/*\/}"
    mkdir -p "RootFolderII/$folder"
    cp -p "$rfipath"/*/Subsub1/* "RootFolderII/$folder"
done
```

Output

```
RootFolderII/FolderA/JPG1.jpg
RootFolderII/FolderA/JPG2.jpg
RootFolderII/FolderB/JPG4.jpg
RootFolderII/FolderB/JPG5.jpg
```

If you really want to use `rsync`, replace the `cp` line with this. It'll gain you the modification times for the directories:

```
for folder in RootFolderI/*
do
    rsync -a "$folder"/*/Subsub1/ "RootFolderII/${folder/*\/}"
done
```